# IBM Worklight - How to integrate Worklight functionality into an existing native app?

Tags: android, ios, ibm-mobilefirst, native

We have a pure native application developed for iOS and Android.

we had plans for migrating the application to Worklight, but that may take lot of time.
Instead of migration, if i integrate the native application with Worklight, what do I gain and what do I lose?

Comment: who ever is voting down the query should also add their comments, simply voting down does not mean any thing to me. its a suggestion.

Comment: I didn't vote it down but it was most likely due to the fact that this is not coding based.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You will not lose anything. Your application will remain a fully native app and you can use any and all features Apple provides in the iOS SDK.
2. Review the below to understand what need to do in order to have your native app connect to the Worklight Server (= integrate the Worklight SDK...), and thus be able to:

   - Implement Worklight Adapters to connect to backend systems
   - Use the Worklight security framework
   - Remote disable and manage applications
   - Unified push notifications
   - etc...

Reading materials:

- Getting Started training modules: [Developing native apps](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#native)
- User documentation: [Developing native apps](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/c_developing_native_apps.html)

(and yes, this is downvoted, because you could have just googled...)

Comment: Thanks Idan, i mean to ask, if i compare it with a hybrid application which is developed using "Worklight", what and all features are not available to me, like "direct update feature" wont be availble in my case. what other features of Worklight i can not use?

Comment: UI-related APIs, as this is a native app you use Apple's SDK to create it; JSONStore (support coming in the future), Direct Update (allowed by Apple only for web resources and not native ones)

Comment: So apart from "Direct update" and "JSON Store", the native application can get benefited from all the other Worklight server's features right?